# Constructing own loginUrl with correct URL encoding

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

As part of my login procedure I'm trying to check that the user has accepted the required permissions.  I have written a function to retrieve the permissions they've accepted and return whether they are correct.  If this returns false I want to construct the loginUrl to direct them to the auth dialog so that they can accept the additional permissions.

```
// Declares the required permissions
        $reqPerms = array(
            'user_status',
            'user_videos'
        );

        $permVer = verifyPermissions($reqPerms);

        if (!$permVer) {
            //$s = "'scope' => '" . implode("','", $reqPerms) . "' ";
            $s = "'".implode("','", $reqPerms)."'";

            echo $s." ";
            $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope' => $s,
                'redirect_uri' => $fbconfig['appUrl']
                ));
print "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
```

This results in the following error below:

```
API Error Code: 100
    API Error Description: Invalid parameter
    Error Message: Unsupported scope: ''user_status''. Supported scopes: ads_management create_event create_note email export_stream friends_about_me friends_activities friends_birthday friends_checkins friends_education_history friends_events friends_games_activity friends_groups friends_hometown friends_interests friends_likes friends_location friends_notes friends_online_presence friends_photo_video_tags friends_photos friends_questions friends_relationship_details friends_relationships friends_religion_politics friends_status friends_subscriptions friends_videos friends_website friends_work_history manage_friendlists manage_notifications manage_pages offline_access photo_upload publish_actions publish_checkins publish_stream read_friendlists read_insights read_mailbox read_page_mailboxes read_requests read_stream rsvp_event share_item sms status_update user_about_me user_activities user_birthday user_checkins user_education_history user_events user_games_activity user_groups user_hometown user_interests user_likes user_location user_notes user_online_presence user_photo_video_tags user_photos user_questions user_relationship_details user_relationships user_religion_politics user_status user_subscriptions user_videos user_website user_work_history video_upload xmpp_login
```

I decided to echo out the `$loginUrl` which I was constructing next to the $loginUrl which is generated automatically if I explicitly reference the permissions 'user_status' and 'user_videos' in the `getLoginUrl()` method.

The scope part of the login url is different, and this apparently has to do with url encoding:

Constructed URL:  `scope=%27user_status%27%2C%27user_videos%27`
Generated URL:    `scope=user_status&0=user_status&1=user_videos`

If I just pass the `$reqPerms` straight into the `getLoginUrl` function I get:  `scope=user_status%2Cuser_videos`

**My question is:  how can edit my code so that the 'scope' part of the URL appears properly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mostly problem is in your

```
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope' => $s,
        'redirect_uri' => $fbconfig['appUrl']
        ));
```

[You could reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/)

The right thing should be:

```
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 
'scope' => 'user_status, user_videos'
) );
```

Comment: Oh my god - that worked!  Thanks a lot!  But why is it that when I include the 'redirect' that it fails?

Comment: you can print($loginUrl), see what is wrong for the url structure and check the wrong part, according to the `Error Message:''user_status''` maybe the Quotes error caused wrong.

Comment: Your attempt failed, because your URL will end up having something like `&scope='foo','bar'&…` in it, whereas the `scope` parameter expects a value of the form `foo,bar` – comma-separated permissions, __without__ single quotes around them.